# Conversion from .shp o .xml gives invalid data

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I tried to convert an ESRI shape file ([jagdgebiete.zip](http://gis.ktn.gv.at/OGD/Land_Forstwirtschaft/jagdgebiete.zip)) with ogr2ogr from the GDAL library with this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES Jagdgebiete.gpx Jagdgebiete.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING
```

But the output is not correct, as it gives e.g. a track-point
`<trkpt lat="154616.85700000077486" lon="545566.38300000037998"></trkpt>`
which is definitely not in the region in question which is approx. 46-46° N and 13°E.

I think the original unit is in metres from a reference point (see [Austria GK M31](https://epsg.io/31258)).

What is the command for `ogr2ogr` to make the correct transformation?

Comment: what  if you add  `-t_srs "EPSG:4326"`?

Comment: When you run `ogr2ogr` do you see `"ERROR 1: Latitude 154616.857000 is invalid. Valid range is [-90,90]. This warning will not be issued any more"` like I do? That's a big clue.

Comment: Rather add `-s_srs epsg:31258`.

Comment: running `$ ogr2ogr -f GPX -s_srs epsg:31258 -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES Jagdgebiete.gpx Jagdgebiete.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING` gives 
`ERROR 1: Latitude 154616.857000 is invalid. Valid range is [-90,90]. This warning will not be issued any more` and did not work

Comment: same for `ogr2ogr -f GPX -t_srs epsg:31258 -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES Jagdgebiete.gpx Jagdgebiete.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING`

Comment: Many thanks for your hints! FYI, ogrinfo gives this report:

`$ ogrinfo -al -so -geom=SUMMARY Jagdgebiete.shp
INFO: Open of `Jagdgebiete.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: Jagdgebiete
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1715
Extent: (398697.585000, 137722.550000) - (582618.981000, 221545.449000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["MGI_Austria_GK_M31",
    GEOGCS["GCS_MGI",
        DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",
            SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
`

Comment: `    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",450000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",-5000000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",13.33333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
OBJECTID: Integer (10.0)
REVIER_ID: Integer (10.0)
REVIER_NAM: String (50.0)
BESCHEID: String (20.0)
TYP: String (22.0)
STAND: Integer (5.0)
SHAPE_AREA: Real (19.11)
SHAPE_LEN: Real (19.11)
`

Comment: Well, I just found out that I used this version of GDAL: `GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26` as this is the one that Linux Mint 17.3 offers. I will update to the latest release and check if it's still an issue

Comment: `ogr2ogr -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES Jagdgebiete.gpx Jagdgebiete.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING -t_srs "EPSG:4326"`works when I install the docker image `$ sudo docker run osgeo/gdal ogrinfo --version
GDAL 3.2.0dev-5e434ad4d80cd43ef35047e2ba76ca13203d3aa2, released 2020/05/08`